# Should I check for residual normality in panel data?

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I'm running a random effects model in R on a large panel. The main specification uses 132 observations.

Should I check for residual normality? 
If I have to, what package/function should I use? 
Otherwise, can I use a simple residual plot on OLS linear model estimations?